# How can I make geom_boxplot outliers "line up" with jittered geom_points?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

How can I make geom_boxplot outliers overlay perfectly with jittered geom_points?

For example, I want the outliers from geom_boxplot to be displayed as "cross hairs" over their actual points from geom_point after jittering?

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=10, outlier.size=8)  +
  geom_point(aes(factor(cyl), mpg, color=mpg),  position="jitter", size=4)
p
```

[image: plot]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution will be quite long. Problem is that with `position="jitter"` you can't get exact coordinates for points, so need to find workaround.

So take your original plot and save it with `ggplot_build()`. First element of data contains information about boxplots. We are interested in column `group` and `outliers` as it shows which values ggplot assumes as outliers. Save them as separate object.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
                geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=10, outlier.size=8)  +
                geom_point(aes(color=mpg),  position="jitter", size=4)
gg<-ggplot_build(p)
gg$data[[1]]
  ymin lower middle upper ymax         outliers notchupper notchlower x PANEL group weight ymin_final
1 21.4 22.80   26.0 30.40 33.9                    29.62055   22.37945 1     1     1      1       21.4
2 17.8 18.65   19.7 21.00 21.4                    21.10338   18.29662 2     1     2      1       17.8
3 13.3 14.40   15.2 16.25 18.7 10.4, 10.4, 19.2   15.98120   14.41880 3     1     3      1       10.4
  ymax_final  xmin  xmax
1       33.9 0.625 1.375
2       21.4 1.625 2.375
3       19.2 2.625 3.375

xx<-gg$data[[1]][c("group","outliers")]
xx
  group         outliers
1     1                 
2     2                 
3     3 10.4, 10.4, 19.2
```

Now change `group` values to 4,6 and 8 to be the same as `cyl` values.

```
xx$group<-c(4,6,8)
```

Now merge this new data frame with original `mtcars` and save as new data frame. Then apply function to check if particulars `mpg` value is listed in `outliers` for that `cyl` level. Those values (TRUE and FALSE) are saved in column `out`.

```
mtcars.new<-merge(mtcars,xx,by.x="cyl",by.y="group")
mtcars.new$out<-apply(mtcars.new,1,function(x) x$mpg %in% x$outliers)
```

Use new data frame to plot data. Remove outliers form `geom_boxplot()`. Use column `out` to determine shape and size of points. With `scale_shape_manual()` and `scale_size_manual()` adjust appearance.

```
ggplot(mtcars.new, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
          geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)  +
          geom_point(aes(color=mpg,shape=out,size=out),  position="jitter")+
          scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,10),guide="none")+
          scale_size_manual(values=c(4,8),guide="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Didzis that a solution that does *exactly* what you aim for is going to be fairly involved. To literally do what you suggest would require (I think) that you do both the jittering and the outlier calculation outside of ggplot. If you're flexible about how you highlight the outliers, this is a potentially shorter solution:

```
id_outliers <- function(x){
    q <- quantile(x,c(0.25,0.75))
    iqr <- abs(diff(q))
    ifelse((x < q[1] - 1.5*iqr) | (x > q[2] + 1.5*iqr),'Outlier','NotOutlier')
}

mtcars <- ddply(mtcars,
                .(cyl),
                transform,
                out = id_outliers(mpg))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA)  + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = mpg,shape = out),position = "jitter")
```